# Invoking Azure Data Factory (V2) pipeline from Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

**Requirement:** I am trying to invoke a ADFV2 pipeline from Azure Function. The ADFV2 pipeline is already created through .NET api.

**Problem**: Not able to resolve `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory` (this one was introduced newly for ADFV2) nuget package where else the nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories` (this one already exists from the timeline of ADFV1) gets successfully accepted.

**Error** - Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory (>= 0.2.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

**Why through Azure Function and not Trigger or Custom Activity**: The ADFV2 pipeline is dependent on another process (the copy activity source dataset might not be ready when the pipeline will be scheduled to run) which could be achieved by .NET custom activity in ADFV2 itself but thought to try in the other possible way around.

**Note**: Already went through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023623/azure-data-factory-how-can-i-trigger-scheduled-onetime-pipelines) which talks about the same thing only difference being its ADFV1.

Comment: Can you point us to the URL for the relevant NuGet package?

Comment: Is this the link you asked - https://libraries.io/nuget/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory

Comment: Are you running on VS 2017? (Since https://libraries.io/nuget/Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory/0.2.1-preview suggests VS 2017 is needed) What version of the .NET Framework is the project using?

Comment: I am trying this from Azure Functions. .NET framework is "4.5.2"
The initial coding for ADFV2 was done from VS 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering and providing some other information so that others who might get stuck on situations like the above would get benefited.

So, finally was able to invoke `ADFV2` pipeline from `Azure Functions` but for some reason was not able to add `Nuget` packages(`Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory`) by referring them in `project.json` or using them directly in `run.csx`. So, uploaded the `dll` in `bin` folder and referred them in my function app as if they were external assemblies which worked fine for my application and was able to invoke all the `ADFV2` pipeline related methods (ex: `DataFactoryManagementClient`, `CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync` etc...).

Also, just started working on `VS2017` (version `15.6.0 preview 1.0`) and checked the `Cloud`->`Azure Functions` application where managing the above mentioned `Nuget` packages is working smoothly.